# Searching for and deleting data within a text file

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, text-files, vb.net-2010

I am currently working on a Library Inventory System.  I wanted it to be able to add, issue, search and delete book records.  The records are stored in a text file which looks like this:

> (ID), (Name Of Book); (Author); (Price) ; (Book Donor) ; (Language)

E.g.

> 123 , Journey to the center of the earth ; Jules Verne ; 50 ; Jack ; English
>   ...

This program also works with a datagridview to update to/from the text file, so far my add and issue functions are working but i am having trouble with search and delete.

To search, the user must either enter the ID of the book in a textbox or the language of the book (separate textbox) and it must show the search results in the datagridview.

This is the my attempt for the search function:

```
    Dim line As String
    Dim fields(7) As String
    Dim found As Boolean = False
    Dim inputStream As StreamReader


    inputStream = File.OpenText("AddBookScreen.txt")
    line = inputStream.ReadLine()

    While (line <> Nothing) And found = False
        fields = Split(line, ",")
        If Trim(fields(0)) = SBidTextbox.Text Then
            SBdatagridview.Rows.Add(Trim(fields(1)), Trim(fields(2)), Trim(fields(3)), Trim(fields(4)), Trim(fields(5)), Trim(fields(6)))
            found = True
        Else
            line = inputStream.ReadLine()
        End If
    End While
    If Not found Then
        MessageBox.Show(SBidTextbox.Text & " not found")

    End If
    inputStream.Close()
End Sub
```

The delete function should be able to find the specific book by id and then delete that record from the text file.

This is my attempt for the delete function:

```
    Dim lines() As String
    Dim outputlines As New List(Of String)
    Dim searchString As String = DBidTextbox.Text
    lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("AddBookScreen.txt")

    For Each line As String In lines
        If line.Contains(searchString) = False Then
            outputlines.Add(line)
        End If
    Next
```

The search and delete methods are meant to search for a specific book in the text file by either the ID of the book or the language and display the results in the datagridview, the delete method is to search for a specific record through ID and delete that record.

Could someone please guide me through these problems, your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the trouble you're having? i.e. what are the search and delete methods doing? Also, this kind of data access is exactly what databases were invented for; if its possible, moving from a text file to a database will make your life much easier.

Comment: are you re-reading the file over and over (and over)?  You could load it into a  `List(Of T)`, work with it and then write it back out when the program ends

Comment: your code shows a `,` delimiter, but your sample data shows both a comma and semi colon

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your text file format slightly (Only use one kind of delimiter - either comma or semi-colon), then you can use the Microsoft Text Driver. This allows you to treat the text file like a database table, and you can use SQL statements to SELECT, DELETE, or UPDATE. Below is an example:

```
Public Sub Delete(ByVal ID As String)
    Dim SQL As String = String.Format("DELETE FROM myfile.csv WHERE ID={0}", ID)
    Dim conn_str As String = String.Format("Driver={{Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}};Dbq={0};Extensions=asc,csv,tab,tsv,txt;", folder)
    Dim conn As New OdbcConnection(conn_str)
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand(sqltxt, conn)
    Dim reader As OdbcDataReader = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    ...

End Sub
```

If this system has any publicly facing user input, I would definitely recommend using a [Parameterized Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i) to prevent SQL injection attacks.